# Get all opened HTML pages by java script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, chromebook

I have a chrome app which are getting user keystroke and screenshot, it is working properly by it self, but I want to get keystroke and screen shot from other opens chrome apps, which I have to get all open pages and inject my script to them, does any body know how can I get the list of all open html pages and also how to inject script to them?

Comment: You could build a [Chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions).

Comment: The extension will not work on chrome native apps

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with Chrome Apps.

They are self-contained by design and cannot interact with the browser this way, let alone other apps.